# Calculate $\int f(x) f''(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a curiosity. If

$\int f(x) f'(x)dx=\int f(x) df(x)=\frac{\left(f(x)\right)^{2}}{2}+C$

what is the result of:

$\int f(x) f''(x)dx$

Comment: Yes. And $\int (f'(x))^2 dx$?

Comment: To write the solution without an integral  is big and deep problem for mathematics.

Comment: @Mathlover, reference please?

Comment: @lhf:I do not know any technics to solve $\int f'(x)^2 dx $  without endless series. if you have a closed form solution of $\int f'(x)^2  dx$ and also you would have a closed form of $\int 4x^2e^{2x^2}  dx$  when  $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ with elemantary functions. They are related to each other. Please see http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf

Comment: @Mathlover, that's a nice observation, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f(x)f'(x)-\int f'(x)^2 \, dx \ ?
$$

Comment: Yes. And $\int (f'(x))^2 dx$?

Comment: In general, nothing: it is what it is.

Comment: This isn't *Jeopardy!*

Comment: @draks What is math.stackexchange?

Answer (score 2):

Using by parts $\int f(x)f''(x)dx= f(x)f'(x)-\int f'^2(x)dx$.